# handle errors in React.js

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

How can I handle errors when there are no results or when a book is not found?

I have the following code :

```
     //states input query
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  //create the states for books
  const [book, setBooks] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const query = e.target.value;
    setQuery(query);
  }
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    axios
      .get(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${query}&maxResults=40`)
      .then((res) => {
       console.log(res.data.items);
        setBooks(res.data.items);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response);
      });
}

const bookAuthors = (authors) => {
  if (!authors) return " Author not available ";
  if (authors.length <= 2) {
    authors = authors.join(" and ");
  } else if (authors.length > 2) {
    let lastAuthor = " and " + authors.slice(-1);
    authors.pop();
    authors = authors.join(", ");
    authors += lastAuthor;
  }
  return authors;
};
```

I want to handle any errors in the following case:

1. Result = 0

What do I need to add for it to work well enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make error as a state
`const [error, setError] = useState(false);`

and call `setError` in your catch statement.
Display error if `error` is not `false`.